# Making a class in Swift 2

Tags: swift, class, public

How should I correctly create such a class which can be used from any `.swift-file` of my project and does not need to be initialized with a variable?

I mean that I want not to have to write something like

```
someVar = myClass()
```

in each file where I want this class to be usable. I just want this class to have a global public variables and change them from a `.swift-file` of my project by doing something like

```
myClass.myVar = value
```

I'm thinking about making this class a separate file. What's a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new class, make a variable off that class outside any class.

```
Class Awesome{
}


let awesomeness = Awesome()
```

you can than use 'awesomeness' as class instance in every other swift file

Answer (score 3):

You can create a static property inside a class or struct and call it anywhere. E.g:

```
//Config.swift
struct Config  
{  
    static var field1 : String = "Field_Value"
    static var field2 : String = "Field_Value"
}
```

You can use the property calling **StructName.propertyName**.
E.g:

```
//MyCode.swift
print(Config.field1)
Config.field1 = "New Value"
```